# Аллокаторы в С++, литература

Tags: c++

Посоветуйте литературу по созданию своих аллокаторов на с++, спасибо.

Comment: Для начала посмотрите большие книги Страуструпа, там есть вводная информация по этой теме, далее - что-то есть у Скотта Майерса.

Comment: @Jenssen спасибо, начну со Страуступа.

Comment: @Jenssen а не подскажете, в какой именно книги от Страуступа содержится данная информация?

Comment: Язык программирования C++ - его книга с описанием возможностей языка. Но там общие сведения по этому вопросу и варианты применения под C++. Вы напишите, какой Вам уровень нужен и что за задача (в общих чертах).

Comment: 631 страница в третьем издании

Comment: @Jenssen >> 631 страница в третьем издании
Вот этого достаточно: ) благодарю Вас.